# help with date query in access

Tags: ms-access

i have field `Tdate` (text type) on my Table `MyTbl`

i need query that sort by date, i try this:

```
select * from MyTbl order by Tdate
```

**but because Tdate is Text i get wrong results**

how to fix it ?  is there any convert to date in access ?

thanks in advance

Comment: how do your dates look like ? Give significant samples...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the `CDate` function like this:

```
select * from MyTbl order by CDate(Tdate)
```

Watch out for potential problems with the date format, e.g. "01/02/2011" could mean 1st Feb or 2nd Jan, the CDate function will use the locale settings on your system.

Comment: That won't use the indexes, unfortunately, and on a large table could be very slow.

Answer (score 1):

I'd run a query to update your text field to use a non-ambiguous, sortable format that works in text, e.g., ISO format, YYYY-MM-DD. A better long-term solution is to change the data type of the field so it's a date so you wouldn't have to muck about with these kinds of problems.